# How to run maxent.jar with -z from command line in Linux

Tags: linux, maxent

I can launch the gui from command line in Linux using:
    `java -mx1500m -jar maxent.jar`

The html output file has the full command line ie.
    `java density.MaxEnt nowarnings noprefixes -E "" -E species1`
 `responsecurves jackknife outputdirectory=/home/user/Documents/output samplesfile=/home/user/Documents/species1.csv` `environmentallayers=/home/user/Documents/allfiles` `noaskoverwrite randomtestpoints=20 -N 1 -N 10 -N 11 -N 12 -N 13 etc etc`

but I can't get this to run. Any ideas?